# Combine 2 collections data with sort and pagination in mongodb and php

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collections user and orders. I want to collect basic info 
like username, firstname from user collection and sum of amount from order table. I can able to select the data by getting info from user collection and looping through order collection. Pagination also works but how to implement sorting with that. How to apply sorting for sum of amount from order collection. My code is given below

```
$cursor = $collection->find($where)->sort($order)->skip($page)->limit($perPage);
    foreach ($cursor as $key => $value) {
        $orderCollection = $this->db->selectCollection('orders');
        $userSubmissions =  $orderCollection->aggregate([
                                ['$match' => ['user_id' => $value['_id'], 'txn_type' => 'DR']],    
                                ['$group' => ['_id' => null, 'debit' => ['$sum' => '$amount']]],
                                ['$sort'  => $order]
                            ]);}
```

Also my collections are

**Usercollection**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59f0546ef2a608770e8b4569"),
"firstname" : "test",
"username" : "test@test.com",
"lastname" : "test",
"status" : NumberLong(1),
"admin" : NumberLong(1),
"created_at" : ISODate("2018-04-02T06:46:53.702Z")}
```

**Ordercollection**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5aaa49d0f2a60838218b4568"),
"user_id" : ObjectId("59f0546ef2a608770e8b4569"),
"txn_type" : "DR",
"name" : "Test Test",
"amount" : 11.85,
"created" : ISODate("2018-03-15T10:24:16.634Z")}
```

So my question is how to sort by using sum of amount?

Expected Output detsils:

[image]

In the above screen shot I want to sort with all the columns and _id, Email Address, firstname, lastname are from user collection and submission and amount spent are from order collection. Also both submission and amount spent from order collection are sum of fields. So how to sort using all columns that?

Comment: Could you post the mongodb version and the expected output?

Comment: my mongodb version is 3.4.10 and I want to join 2 tables for the sorting column. One of the column is sum of table.

Comment: Could you post the expected output. So that it will be easier to answer

Comment: @Anthony Winzlet thanks for the reply and I have added the expected output details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": ObjectId("59f0546ef2a608770e8b4569") }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "orders",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "user_id",
    "as": "orders"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$orders" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$orders.user_id",
    "debit": { "$sum": "$orders.amount" },
    "firstname": { "$first": "$firstname" },
    "lastname": { "$first": "$lastname" },
    "email": { "$first": "$username" }
  }}
])
```

You can use `$sort` with any of the fields in the above aggregation. Just use `{ $sort: { fieldName: 1 }}`

Comment: Thanks @ Anthony Winzlet. This is worked for me with adding $sort for each column dynamically.